# Highcharts not showing string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, local-storage

I'm trying to add localstorage values into highchart series but it doesn't work.

When i print the "newString" value on the console and replace the value for "newString" at the code it works but it doesn't when I use `var newString`.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var archive,
        j = "",
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        x = keys.length;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < x) {
        archive = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keys[i]));
        j += "{ name: " + keys[i] + ", data: [" + archive.username + ", " + archive.email + ", " + archive.password + "]},";
        i++;
    }
    var newString = j.substr(0, j.length - 1);
    console.log('newString: ', newString);

    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
            text: 'Datos ingresados'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Localstorage'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Datos ingresados'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                label: {
                    connectorAllowed: false
                },
                pointStart: 2017
            }
        },

        series: [
            newString
        ],

        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    });

});
```

This is what console.log shows:

> { name: 2, data: [12345, 23456, 34567]},{ name: 3, data: [23456, 34567, 45678]},{ name: 4, data: [34567, 45678, 56789]},{ name: 5, data: [45678, 56789, 67890]}

When I change the value of newString for that, it works properly.

Comment: One is of type `string` and the other is a complex `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second case, `Highcharts` see your data as a pure string. So, you need to parse your string.

But first of all, we should create valid json for parsing correctly:

```
var newString = "{ name: 2, data: [12345, 23456, 34567]}"; //bad json
var json = newString.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2":');
var goodJson = "[" + json + "]"; //valid json
```

Now we can create options for the `Highcharts`:

```
var options = {
   chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     type: 'spline'
   },
   series: []
};
```

And push data to `series` as follows:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(goodJson), function(i, item) { 
   options.series.push({
    name: item.name,
    data: item.data
   });
});
```

And finally initialize `Highcharts`:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

---

**[See at Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KPLCHyvjykReWuEXb1EC?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i dont understand what to do with the options part, when i create that variable and try to excecute the code, the console launch this error message "Cannot read property 'series' of undefined".

Comment: @JorgeSeminario  I added plunker in the answer. you can see working code there. you can change all your code after `console.log('newString: ', newString);` line to my code. You create highcharts with options above, but at my code, I create option variable first and then pass it to highcharts as a parameter.